# Ruby parallel looping through mysql output

Tags: mysql, ruby, multithreading, parallel-processing, fork

I created script to get data from MySQL and push it to some REST API. I have around 30k entries to go through and it is very slow.
I was trying to do loops in parallel but did not find/get it. can you help me how to accomplish it?

Code looks like:

```
require 'mysql'


begin

con = Mysql.new 'els-hq-imdb', 'netops', 'mapMyPorts', 'eic'
#getting all entries for infodots
rs = con.query "SELECT ip.ip,  omitted ***"

puts "We have #{rs.num_rows} row(s)"


rs.each_hash do |row|

    p pduip =row['ip']

end
rescue Mysql::Error => e
    puts e    
ensure
    con.close if con
end
```

Big thank you in advance! 
D

Comment: are you sure the bottleneck is in the loop? could it be because you are loading `30k` objects in memory?

Comment: Bottleneck is in REST API calls. memory resource is not saturated